# check if a string contain specific words in the start should remove-JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to remove any label that begins with M#- or L#- 
this rule should be in jquery/javascript that any label that begins with M#- or L#- should return false
labels example:

```
Live
M1- My Choice, 
Stage
M2- Site, 
KFC
L1- 1KFC, 
L2- New Choice
```

Result:

```
Live    
Stage
KFC
```

Comment: use regular expression

Comment: what will be expression for this

Comment: if (label.indexOf("M1- ") > -1)
        return false;

Answer (score 1):

Use Regular expression

http://jsfiddle.net/4GXeW/

```
var string = "M1-";

if(string.match('[a-zA-Z0-9]-')){
alert("false");
    //return false
}
```

String can have any label value.

Answer (score 0):

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/GqGLt/1

```
var reg = new RegExp('^[ML][0-9]');

var array = ["Live", "M1- My Choice", "Stage", "M2- Site", "KFC", "L1- 1KFC", "L2- New Choice"];

$.each(array, function(idx, val){
   console.log(val, !reg.test(val)); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this is through the use of regular expressions.

```
var regex = /[ML][0-9]-.*/;
var pattern = new RegExp(regex);

var arr = [
  "Live",
  "M1- My Choice, ",
  "Stage",
  "M2- Site, ",
  "KFC",
  "L1- 1KFC, ",
  "L2- New Choice"
]

for (var x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
  if(arr[x].match(pattern)!==null){
    arr.splice(x, 1);
    x--;
  }
}
```

This will remove all of the L1- etc labeled columns from the arr array.

```
arr = ["Live", "Stage", "KFC"];
```